# Execute stored procedure with one parameter as an input

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedure. My stored procedure is

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_HouseHoldMembers]
(
@StudentID varchar
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT MemberID,FirstName+''+LastName,Age,Sex,Education
FROM Student SD 
WHERE SD.StudentID=@StudentID
END
```

I execute it like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_HouseHoldMembers] @StudentID='123'
```

BUT ITS NOT SHOWING THE RESULT AND WHEN I execute it simply by using simple query taking this `123` as an input then it gives the desired result.

Please someone tell where i am going wrong

Comment: Please format your questions correctly - [see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: When you did `EXEC [dbo].[SP_HouseHoldMembers] @StudentID='123'`, did you have a semicolon at the end of the statement (or is that just a typo in the question)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your using this parameter:

```
@StudentID varchar
```

This is a **1 charactrer string**, so passing `'123'` is truncated to `'1'`

Instead;

```
@StudentID int
```

or

```
@StudentID varchar(<insert appropriate size>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. WHat a ridiculous mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your parameter to be `varchar` - that means: variable length string of **1 character length**!!

You need to give that `varchar` a explicit length!

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_HouseHoldMembers]
(@StudentID varchar(20) )
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT MemberID,FirstName + '' + LastName, Age, Sex, Education
   FROM Student SD 
    WHERE SD.StudentID = @StudentID
END
```